# Does HAProxy support cluster?

Tags: haproxy

I am deploying an NodeJS application on AWS. The current structure is

ELB <===> 1 HAProxy instance <===> 2+ EC2 instances running NodeJS application

The Single HA Proxy instance ensures that ELB always route the session to the HAProxy instance and HAProxy instance can use its own stickiness strategy to ensure sticky sessions.

My question is how I can add more HAProxy instances to this architecture. I could not find any info about HAProxy cluster and how they work and how to configure in HAProxy's documentation. Is cluster supported by HAProxy?

Answer (score 2):

According to my understanding, haproxy will provide stick table syncing through its peering connections, but will not support connection counting stats syncing.

If you have a server cluster on the backend that has a limited number of threads (puma/rails), you will have to adjust your min-max backend connections if you run haproxy in active-active mode.

Two haproxy servers each with 1000 be connections you will actually need 2000 be connections (100 puma workers with 20 threads),

So, to make things simple, I just run two haproxies in active-hot-standby mode.  Each configured to support the same backend thread pool.

Running haproxy on a c4.xlarge is quite sufficient to handle 1000 backend connections with 2000 sumultaneous frontend connections on full flood test with 150,000 users.

Oh, and your ELB is redundant.  Take it out.  You are paying 200/month for your HAPE and 25/month for your ELB.

They do the same thing.  Use one or the other.  Not both.  If you want ELB, then you will need WAF to get the same functionality haproxy gives you.

By the way, my haproxy also has a nodeJS app as a backend.  I set min-max connections as necessary based on load test performance metrics for my node server.

Oh, and don’t try to serve your node application with an ELB.  You need http-mode request buffering to serve your node application.  Haproxy gives that to you.

I use a ELK monitoring cluster to monitor haproxy.  If it fails, I am notified.  But, I do not move ip addresses.  Route53 with failover dns will automatically remove the failed haproxy from the DNS pool of it fails (within 60 seconds... not ideal).  If you need a fixed IP, the story is different.  If you polled every 10 seconds, you could move the IP address with the service on a monitoring server within 15 seconds maybe.

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

You can try pairing up multiple HAProxy instances with keepalived service which will provide VRRP between them. As an entry level description you can follow

> http://support.severalnines.com/entries/23612682-Install-HAProxy-and-Keepalived-Virtual-IP-

Comment: Sounds promising. How can I do that in AWS? Do I need a third EC2 instance to install keepalived?

Answer (score 1):

HAProxy doesn't have a clustering concept. But you can have multiple HAproxy servers working together with Keepalived service. Keepalived worked on master-slave concept and keeps trace of HAproxy server check. Once master server goes down it change route to slave server.